# Change theme to button

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-theme

Hi I have 1 activity with 3 buttons,I have now created the ability to change the theme app, and up here all okay but I do not know how to go from buttoshape.xml to buttoshape_blue.xml
This is my theme:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_blue</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/bianco</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Red" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_red</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/bianco</item>


    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


</style>
```

this my button in xml

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/magic_item"
    android:text="Magic Item"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    />
```

and this is my buttonshape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="90%"
    android:centerColor="#ec2127"
    android:startColor="#CC1414"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"
    />
```

my Utility

```
public class Utility {


    public static void setTheme(Context context, int theme) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        prefs.edit().putInt(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), theme).apply();
    }
    public static int getTheme(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return prefs.getInt(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), -1);
    }
}
```

and BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int THEME_BLUE = 1;
    private final static int THEME_RED = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        updateTheme();
    }
    public void updateTheme() {
        if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) <= THEME_BLUE) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColorDark_blue));
            }
        } else if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) == THEME_RED) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColorDark_red));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom theme attribute which would contain a reference to the background to use and set it to *@drawable/buttonshape* for *AppTheme.Red* and to *@drawable/buttonshape_blue* for *AppTheme.Blue*.

E.g. in *values* you could have an *attrs.xml* file in which there would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="buttonBackground" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

and in your themes.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_blue</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/bianco</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/bianco</item>
    <item name="buttonBackground">@drawable/buttonshape_blue</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Red" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_red</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/bianco</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="buttonBackground">@drawable/buttonshape</item>

</style>
```

Your button in the layout file would look like this:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/magic_item"
...
android:background="?attr/buttonBackground"
...
/>
```